# types.MethodType vs functools.partial

Tags: python, functional-programming

This is a continuation of my other question ([python closure + oop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692423/python-closure-oop)). In the answer to that question, Winston Ewert suggested me to use `functools.partial` instead of `types.MethodType`.

So now my question is: what's the difference between the two? Why is the functool way considered better?

ps. I've managed to use functools.partial for my closure and it did feel cool. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a practical stand point, there isn't a whole lot of difference.  Partial will curry any number of arguments (in this case, 1); an instancemethod will pass the self instance (whatever that happens to be) to the wrapped function;  They're doing the same thing!

The difference is that they somewhat document themselves;  In your linked question; the `closure` callable isn't a method of anything; it's a regular function, returned by a method of `A`;  It happens that the body sees an instance of `B` as the first argument; but that's not enough to make it a "method" of B.

So it's just a matter of style.  You're doing something that looks more like `functools.partial`, and so you should use that, even though you can achieve the same effect with `types.MethodType`